# Why does it show question marks on the message box instead of text

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

Why does it shows question marks on the message box instead of text

[image]

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://teamxor.net/vb/tx48/"+ page);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

string result = sr.ReadToEnd();

Regex r = new Regex("<div>.*?</div>");
MatchCollection mr = r.Matches(result);

foreach (Match m in mr)
{
    MessageBox.Show(m.Value, "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. Can you please show your work as well?

Comment: Check font and encoding.

Comment: Obviously it's encoding issues, but posting code would be helpful.

Comment: maybe it just mean the system does not have that font installed.

Comment: check in debug what are these signs

Comment: @kennyzx I think you are Right how can I know the font of a certain website ?

Comment: You can find the encoding used from the HttpWebRespone.CharacterSet property. Don't assume a page has a specific encoding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem lies in the use of a non-default code page. Your HTML shows you are using code page 1256. You have to tell .NET that, else it thinks it is UTF-8:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( response.GetResponseStream()
                                  , Encoding.GetEncoding(1256) // <-- this one
                                  );
```

Use [`Encoding.GetEncoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332096%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to get the right code page. I suggest to use UTF8 instead, since that is easily recognized by .NET.

Comment: Actually, since this is a WebResponse, the OP should always check and use the `charset` header

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: You mean the HTML header? I think it is too late for that at that moment already.

Comment: No, I mean the HTTP header. The HTML header doesn't affect the actual data encoding. The web server will put the encoding used in the `charset` header.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: There is none.

Comment: Using Fiddler, you'll see the HTTP response `Content-Type` header is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1256`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: My bad. Overlooked that one. Was looking for `charset` ;)

Answer (score 4):

Web servers can return a response in whatever encoding they want, although they typically choose an encoding that matches the browser's preferred language.

The encoding used is returned as the `charset` element of the `Content-Type` header. In .NET you can retrieve the encoding used from the [HttpWebResponse.CharacterSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.characterset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. You can use the returned charset to construct an Encoding object to use for reading the response:

```
var charset= response.CharacterSet;
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(charset);
var sr= new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),encoding);
....
```